# Is initializing non static members allowed outside of a class constructor?

Tags: c++, initialization

I just saw a question where a non static member of a class was initialized in the class definition. But if I try to compile the following code I get an error from the compiler.

```
class MyClass
{
    int n = 2;
};
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
g++ -o ns nonstatic.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
nonstatic.cpp:3:13: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member ‘n’ [-fpermissive]
nonstatic.cpp:3:13: error: making ‘n’ static [-fpermissive]
nonstatic.cpp:3:13: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘n’
```

I always thought I must initialize such member in the constructor like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass ( void ) : n(2) {}
    private:
        int n;
};
```

Or with `n` initialized inside of the body of the constructor.
So my question is: when is one allowed to initialize a non static member outside the context of a class constructor?

kind regards,

Comment: By the way, what it does is initialize the member in constructors that otherwise don't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> when is one allowed to initialize a non static member of a class in C++?

One can do this already in C++11.

Just pass in `-std=c++11` to the command line and you'll be able to.

Comment: If i do that my compiler tells me it's not implemented it yet I'm compiling on Ubuntu with g++ 4.6.3 . Do newer versions of g++ support it?

Comment: Experimental support has started from gcc 4.7 onwards.[see](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)

Comment: In non-C++11, you can only do integer types, I think. I forget the exact rules. Recent versions of GCC has implemented almost all of C++11's language features, and some of the library features.

Comment: @JaminGrey It think my example shows that in pre C++11 one can't do so:)

Comment: @hetepeperfan You can if they are `const` integral types.

Comment: @JaminGrey, IIRC, static const integral members in C++03, non-static members in C++11, and static constexpr members in C++11.

Comment: Oops I'm missing a `static` in my last comment. Time to rub the balloon some more.